# Getting Error code : AUTH-006 , for https://developer-dev.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/metadata/:guid/properties

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

Even though I am able to call and get proper response for a revit model already translated, https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/metadata or   https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/manifest , with the token generated from client_id and client_secret, the same token along with the modelGuid received from the metadata api call, when used with https://developer-dev.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/metadata/:guid/properties , I am getting error with "developerMessage": "Access token provided is invalid or expired.", Similar is the situation for https://developer-dev.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/metadata/:guid/properties:query.

My goal is to call the post api : https://developer-dev.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/metadata/:guid/properties:query and find whether an externalId exists in a model or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that some sample codes accidentally used the **internal** endpoints with `developer-dev.api` in the **URL**, e.g.:  https://developer-dev.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/metadata/:guid/properties - maybe that's how you ended up trying them? 
Those are not for 3rd parties.

You should only use endpoints with `developer.api` in the **URL**.